# 70s(?) film with rich folks using guns to burn trees for fun?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to find 70s, perhaps 80s, movie with a scene in which rich folks get drunk and shoot trees with futuristic guns setting them on fire.

Not a great movie, as I recall, but a memorable scene.

Comment: Logan's Run? There's a scene where they shoot near a runner

Comment: On the contrary, it is really quite a good movie!

Comment: I've got an informal "identify famous movies from a scene no one remembers" list and this is going on it. FYI: Rollerball is famous for Tocatta in D-minor (creepy organ music), the corporation reassigning your wife to someone else, and punching people on flaming motorcyles with a spiked gauntlet holdnig a steel ball while a crowd chants Jon-a-thon.

Comment: I agree with "Not a great move"  It was an amazing movie!  :P  just a fond memory from my youth that does not hold up well.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This sounds like it could be *[Rollerball](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073631/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, a 1975 science fiction film starring James Caan. Although it is most famous for the violent sporting scenes, it did include a passage where after a party a group of drunken guests staggered outside and set trees on fire using some kind of futuristic gun.

From the DVD commentary :

> "Here is a scene where I wanted to devise something that would
> demonstrate the lack of morality, the lack of any kind of sensitive
> protection of something that was... that was alive and could be
> destroyed... a tree like this would take maybe 125 years, 150 years of
> life, and you will see it destroyed in an instant. Which is a warning
> I was trying to give of the lack of understanding of certain forces in
> the world that had no respect or little respect for the environment
> and living things, and where that would lead to because the greed of
> man indeed is destroying forests all over the world and as these few
> are left it gave us an opportunity to show that for fun and sport they
> would destroy a living thing in an instant."

You can see this scene on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhwdkvfxlCY).

Comment: Nice. And a quote from the commentary too. You have my+1 and will be getting a wee bonus for going above and beyond the call of duty

Comment: Thank you @Valorum much appreciated! Although we don't know yet if the answer is correct

Comment: Even if it's not right, it's still a solid example of an excellent answer.

Comment: Yup that's it! Well done. It's a film that certainly has its moments - the scoreboard saying HOU v MAD sticks in my mind, but it didn't totally work for me. Ripe for a remake, but I hope they leave it alone.

Comment: [Wikipedia suggests there was a remake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollerball_(2002_film)) and.... Apparently the real life drama around the movie was much better than the movie

Comment: The remake gets 3% on Rotten Tomatoes! Is that the worst ever? It's quite a prophetic film really - a TV game show where contestants fight dirty and often maim each other . I must rewatch the original.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The original was a fine dystopian science fiction film.  It actually has a subtle way of drawing the viewer into getting excited about the titular sport and rooting for the Houston team, then reminded them how brutal and political it actually is.  Thus the insidious propaganda role played by the game comes through very clearly.  The remake apparently missed all this complexity, and the filmmakers just wanted to make a totally gung-ho action film valorizing the violent sport.

Comment: I'll own up to being old enough to remember the release. It was a briliant time for serious scifi - dare I say much better than now, despite the glut we have! We'd just had Clockwork Orange, Omega Man, Soylent Green, Andromeda Strain, Westworld, Dark Star, THX 1138 (no, not the awful director's cut!) ,Zardoz, Solaris... 
Rollerball had some very interesting ideas, and was indeed prophetic, but it was very on-the-nose and lacked subtlety.
I think this is one we'll just have to agree to diagree on. ;-)

Comment: Meanwhile, the clip shows 6 trees on fire, then the scene shifts to the arena, where Jonathan 6 is the hero. I'm pretty sure this isn't coincidence.